# server recognizes comma as a string

Tags: laravel

So basically i have an input type text which is validated to contain only numbers, comma and dot. When i enter(5.32) for example everything is okay but when i enter (5,32) it won't let me submit it, because it recognizes it as a string, which i don't want. How can i convert the comma into a dot in backend and still show as a comma ?

`<input type="text" name="monthly_price" id="monthly_price"  value=""   class="comma-validation">`

```
    $('.comma-validation').on('input', function() {
        var currentInput = $(this).val();
        var fixedInput = currentInput.replace(/[^0-9 \,.]/, '');
        $(this).val(fixedInput);
    });
```

Comment: What's the datatype in the backend?

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 It comes as a string.

Comment: From the form, yes. But in your migration, or in the database, what is the data type you are storing it as?

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 UnsignedDecimal

Comment: Can you show some of your server side code and the error being thrown.

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 This is the error thrown. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
Basicly all i am asking for is how i can manipulate and tell the server that the comma is dot. Like just appear as dot. Something with str replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you can do:

```
$monthlyPrice = (float)str_replace(',', '.', request('monthly_price'));
```

This replaces the comma into a decimal. Then casts it as a float.